# Group by is case sensitive in T-SQL even though db and server collations are CI

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have not found any documentation that explains the following behavior, both db and server level collation are CI (Case Insensitive), why is it still case sensitive in this aspect?

```
--Works
SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name, COUNT(value) FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
)a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END

--Returns an Error Message, please note the "B" in Bertrand in the GROUP BY
SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END name, COUNT(value) FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
)a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'Bertrand' END
```

The second query returns this error message.

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Column 'a.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: As you may have seen I am not using any tables in my example and am still able to produce this behavior so there is no table or column to check collation for.

Comment: Oh and my tempdb is also CI.

Comment: You should note the error that you're getting when you try to run that second query.  I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32728).  I have no idea what CI sql fiddle is at, but it seems clear that your group by and select need to be exact.

Comment: This question isn't off-topic, but you might get better/faster answers over at [dba.se].

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't check the semantics of the expression to see if it would be affected by case sensitivity. E.g. The following would still group differently on a CI collation `ASCII('A') % value` and `ASCII('a') % value`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more of extended comment that real answer.

I believe this issue is coming from how SQL Server is attempting to evaluate `case` statement expression.

To prove that server is case insensetive you can run the following two statements

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'Bertrand' = 'bertrand' THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' end
```

-

```
DECLARE @base TABLE
(NAME VARCHAR(1)
,value INT
)
INSERT INTO @base Values('a',0),('b',0),('B',0)

SELECT * FROM @base

SELECT name, COUNT(value) AS Cnt
FROM @base
GROUP BY NAME
```

---

results:

[image]

as you can see here even though letter in second row is lower case and in third row is upper case, group by clause ignores the case. Looking at execution plan there are two expression for

```
Expr 1007 COUNT([value])    
Expr 1004 CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1007],0)
```

---

now when we change it to `case`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name, COUNT(value) AS Cnt
FROM @base
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END
```

execution plan shows 3 expressions. 2 from above and new one

```
Expr 1004 CASE WHEN [NAME]='a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END
```

so at this point aggregate function is no longer evaluating value of the column `name` but now it evaluating value of the expression.

What i think is happening is, could be incorrect. When SQL server converts both `CASE` statement in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clause to a expression it comes up with different expression value. In this case you might as well do `'bertrand'` in `select` and `'charlie'` 
in `group by` clause because if `CASE` expression is not 100% match between select and group by clause SQL Server will consider them as different `Expr` aka (columns) that no longer match.

---

Update:

To take this one step further, the following statement will also fail.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE UPPER('bertrand') END AS name
    ,COUNT(value) AS Cnt
FROM @base
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE UPPER('Bertrand') END
```

Even wrapping the different case strings in `UPPER()` function, SQL Server is still unable to process it.

Comment: If you capitalize the B in both statements it works just fine. You are 100% correct sir. It is comparing the case to the case in the `SELECT` seeing that they do not match and throwing a fit as a result. It has nothing to do with CI.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Oselsky for this answer, I feel like this is as far as we can get in interpreting why the evaluation of the query works as it does in this case.

Comment: I still find it a bit strange that since the upper test you did fails but this does not:

SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'b'+'ertrand' END AS name
    ,COUNT(value) AS Cnt
FROM @base
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name = 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the case when statement in select and group by should be same, but you can write your query as below

```
select name, count(value) from
(
    SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END name, value FROM
        (
        SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
        UNION
        SELECT 'b',1
        UNION
        SELECT 'b',2
        )a
    )t
GROUP BY name
```

---

This is not about case sensivity, take a look at this sample

```
This works

SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' when 'b' then 'bertrand' end name, COUNT(value) FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
)a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' when 'b' then 'bertrand' END


This does not work
SELECT CASE name when 'b' then 'bertrand' WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' end name, COUNT(value) FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
)a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' when 'b' then 'bertrand' END
```

While the case of  'adam' and 'bertrand' are the same.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the second query doesn't work.

Comment: @Szymon, he says right in the answer, the `statement in select and group by should be same`

Comment: But what does that *exactly* mean? That's a vague statement. For case insensitive collation, `'B' = 'b'`

Comment: I agree that this is the prolem "[...]is the case when statement in select and group by should be same" but WHY is it case sensitive even though my collation at server, tempdb and currentdatabase level is not? It is not documented as case sensitive at the t-sql msdn page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: Now it's very obviously different so what does that prove? Obviously 'a' <> 'b'

Comment: @Szymon in the example the result of case is the same, I just change the order of them, I don't know what sql exactly is doing in the projection of case statement in group by, but I know that the statement should be exactly the same.

Comment: No, there's some logic and restrictions here. Replace one `'bertrand'` with `'b' + 'ertrand'` and it still works.

Comment: If you change any letter in that Case to a capital it will not work as it is a snytax error. Your `Group By CASE` must match you `SELECT CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

You have found something that is genuinely weird, but I think the problem is that you are using the case statement at all in the group by statement. It should be:

```
SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name   FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
) a
GROUP BY name
```

The group by should apply to the entire table and not individual rows. I could be missing some reason to do this, but I don't think it makes sense to conditionally group by a value.

I am more surprised that the first one works at all than that the second one doesn't work. Comparing 'a' = 'A' is subtly different from comparing a column to another column. SQL server doesn't seem to use the collation settings in this check to see if the column is in the group by. The error message you receive from your second query is saying 'this column in the select is not the same as the column in the group by' and not 'these values are not equal'.

Comment: `/*An example of the difference with group by using case*/
SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name   FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
UNION
SELECT 'c',3
) a
GROUP BY name

SELECT CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name   FROM
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'b',1
UNION
SELECT 'b',2
UNION
SELECT 'c',3
) a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END`

Answer (score 0):

Define does't work
On your second I get a syntax error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'a.name' is invalid in the
> select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
> function or the GROUP BY clause.

At this point it has not even tried to process the query
Why do you insist the syntax error is because CI is not honored

It is a syntax error - not an execution error
The select must match the group by
So for some reason the SQL parser requires matching case
What matters is how it process the query

If you had case sensitive tables would you expect TSQL to require case sensitive column and table names?

This work for me
adam sums to 6
it honors both the lower (a) and upper case (A)

This demonstrates that this group by IS case insensitive

```
SELECT CASE a.name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END AS name, sum(value)
from 
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'a',2
UNION
SELECT 'A',3
UNION
SELECT 'b',10
UNION
SELECT 'b',20
UNION
SELECT 'B',30
) as a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'a' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'bertrand' END
```

and this honors case insensitive

```
SELECT CASE a.name WHEN 'A' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'Bertrand' END AS name, sum(value)
from 
(
SELECT 'a' AS name,1 AS value
UNION
SELECT 'a',2
UNION
SELECT 'A',3
UNION
SELECT 'b',10
UNION
SELECT 'b',20
UNION
SELECT 'B',30
) as a
GROUP BY CASE name WHEN 'A' THEN 'adam' ELSE 'Bertrand' END
```

Comment: @Zane How did it not answer the question?  The results of the query are case insensitive.  OP asked why they were not case insensitive.  A syntax error is not a processing error.  If the table was case sensitive you expect SELECT to be different from select or suddenly the column names must honor case?

Comment: It fails because he has a syntax error.  Not because group by is case sensitive.  adam sums to 6

Comment: @Zane This is not clear enough "Column 'a.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  I provide valid syntax using both matching 'a' and matching 'A'.  Both produce the expected result.

Comment: Do you realise that the error in the OP's second query goes away once the `Bertrand` in the GROUP BY is changed to `bertrand`? *That* is the question, i.e. why CI is not honoured in that situation.

Comment: @Zane Please read the title.  "group by is case sensitive even if the table is not"  This answer demonstrates that assertion is not true.   He has a second problem in using invalid syntax to test that assertion.  See other comments on other question.  OP has already been told it is a problem with matching the select to the where and the OP dismissed that answer.

Comment: @AndriyM Because the query parser has nothing to do with table collation. Honoring CI in the query execution and query parsing are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>This is not an answer but a comment that happens to require more room and capabilities than the Comments section offers.</sub>

If the underlying problem is to minimise the risk of making such a blunder in your queries because of having to maintain a complex expression both in GROUP BY and in SELECT, then you could avoid the repetition in the first place by using [CROSS APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx). Instead of

```
SELECT SomeComplexExpression, SomeAggregation
FROM ...
GROUP BY SomeComplexExpression;
```

you could do

```
SELECT x.GroupingCriterion, SomeAggregation
FROM ...
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SomeComplexExpression AS GroupingCriterion) AS x
GROUP BY x.GroupingCriterion;
```

and now you would need to maintain the complex grouping expression in a single place.

Hopefully you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version to be able to use this method. Otherwise you can always use a derived table:

```
SELECT GroupingCriterion, SomeAggregation
FROM (
  SELECT SomeComplexExpression AS GroupingCriterion, OtherData
  FROM ...
) AS s
GROUP BY GroupingCriterion;
```

The final query is less elegant this way but the same result is achieved: the expression is defined just once.